# Some confusion with conversion of FROM clauses into a call to SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Two subsequent *FROM* clauses get translated into a call to `SelectMany`.

a)

```
var query = from c_1 in collection_1
            from c_2  in collection_2 
            from c_3 in collection_3
            select ...
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think query expression gets translated into a code semantically equivalent to:

```
collection_1.SelectMany(c_1 => c_1.collection_2.
               SelectMany(c_2 => c_2.collection_3.
                     Select(c_3 =>  ... )));
```

Is `from c_3 in collection`  always "*bound*" to `c_2` range variable? With the term "*bound*" I'm asking whether the entire `collection_3` gets enumerated for each `c_2` element?

b) Assuming I'm correct under ***a)***, is `c_3` always "*bound*" to range variable defined closest to it?

c) If answer to ***b)*** is true, then `c_3` is bound to `c_2` even in the following example:

```
var query = from c_1 in collection_1
            from c_2  in collection_2 
            where ...
            from c_3 in collection_3
```

d) Is in next query `c_3` bound to `a` ( ie for each `a` the entire `groupAandB` will be enumerated ):

```
var query_1 =  from a in groupA
               join b in groupB on a equals b
                  into groupAandB
               from c_3 in groupAandB
               select c_3;
```

e) Here I'm assuming that answer to ***d)*** is that `c_3` is indeed bound to `a`. But when looking at the code into which `query_1` is translated at compile time, we could instead argue that `c_3` is actually bound to anonymous type `a_1` ( ie `new { a, groupAandB = os }` )?!

```
groupA.GroupJoin(groupB, a => a, b => b, (a, os) => new { a, groupAandB = os } ).
             SelectMany(a_1 => a_1.groupAandB );
```

f) Keeping in my mind into what `query_1` gets translated, couldn't we argue that any assumptions I made under ***d)*** are perhaps conceptually correct, but technically wrong, since at compile time there isn't any `c_3` variable, or perhaps there is `c_3` defined somewhere under the hood, but it is actually bound to an *anonymous type* and not to `a`?

**EDIT:**

1)

> with Join, the "second" collection can't depend on which value you're
>   currently "looking at" from the first collection,

a) I assume you essentially mean that we can't join `customers` to a collection ( ie `c.Orders` ) returned by current value of `c` :

```
var query1 = from c in customers
             join o in c.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.OrderID // this won't work
             select new { c.Name, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate };
```

b) Btw, why is such a join not allowed ( I'm assuming it would be technically feasible to make such a join ) or perhaps why it doesn't make sense?

2)

> "The C# specification gives the explicit transformation involved"

Could you elaborate what you mean by *"explicit transformation involved"* and how it relates to ***e)*** and ***f)*** questions?

thank you

Comment: Sorry, I got lost at c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query a gets compiled to:

```
collection1
   .SelectMany(c1 => collection2, (c1, c2) => new { c1, c2 })
   .SelectMany(t0 => collection3, (t0, c2) => new { t0.c1, t0.c2, c3 })
;
```

`collection2` is enumerated for each element in `collection1`; `collection3` is enumerated for every combination of items in the result.

If `collection1` contains `{ 1, 2 }`, `collection2` contains `{ 11, 12 }`, and `collection3` contains `{ 21, 22 }`, then the result will be:

```
|----|----|----|
| c1 | c2 | c3 |
|----|----|----|
|  1 | 11 | 21 |
|  1 | 11 | 22 |
|  1 | 12 | 21 |
|  1 | 12 | 22 |
|  2 | 11 | 21 |
|  2 | 11 | 22 |
|  2 | 12 | 21 |
|  2 | 12 | 22 |
|----|----|----|
```

Query c gets compiled to:

```
collection1
   .SelectMany(c1 => collection2, (c1, c2) => new { c1, c2 })
   .Where(t0 => ...)
   .SelectMany(t0 => collection3, (t0, c3) => new { t0.c1, t0.c2, c3 })
;
```

`collection3` is enumerated for every combination of items from `collection1` and `collection2` which pass the filter.

For query d, each `c_3` will be the list of items from `groupB` which match an element from `groupA`, so if I've understood your terminology correctly, it is indeed "bound to" `a`.

Comment: Are at least semantically queries a,c and e ( those using method syntax ) correct - meaning would they ALWAYS produce identical results to those returned by a,c and d query expressions?

Comment: As far as I can see, they should be correct. Your method-syntax version of query a is slightly different to the code that actually gets called, but it should produce the same results. Your best bet is probably to try the query-syntax in LinqPad, use the `.AsQueryable()` extension on your collections if necessary, and `.Dump()` the query; LinqPad will then show the Lambda syntax in a separate tab.

Comment: @user1483278: The C# specification gives the explicit transformation involved - and yes, these are the correct translations as far as I can see. Note that there's a difference between `Join` and `SelectMany` though - with `Join`, the "second" collection can't depend on which value you're currently "looking at" from the first collection, whereas with `SelectMany` it can, even though you don't use that here.

Comment: @user1483278: Well did you try reading the C# specification? Search for "query expression" and you should be able to find the relevant section. It's pretty self-contained.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes,I've read it but it hasn't answered my questions

Comment: @user1483278: Well it certainly answers the question of the explicit transformation. Now I'm home, I can refer to it - section 7.16 of the C# 4 spec gives copious details. Which *exact* question does that not answer?

Comment: Ups, I was looking at C# 3 specs ( where section 7.16 covers assignments ) thinking they were C# 4 spec. Apologies and thank you very much for your help